# Drawing graphs in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams, graphs

Is it possible to draw graphs like in image below in LaTeX?
It doesn't have to look exactly the same. I need arrows with numbers and circles (or dots or other symbol) with text in it (or next to it).

[image]

Comment: You could use the TikZ `automata` library. For an example, see http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/state-machine/

Comment: By which pkg would you create a hypercube graph? I feel this specific question does not fall under this question, moved it [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129613/by-which-pkg-to-visualize-a-hypercube-graph).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Here's an example, showing how you could do it with TikZ in a short and readable way.

- Define styles for edges, arrows, and nodes

  - `circle` style for the main nodes, and `font` options so we don't need to adjust fonts within the nodes
  - For arrows, we use `stealth'` which is the name for a kind of arrow tip and `shorten` to not touch the node
  - The option `auto` is useful for automatic placement of nodes next to edges, instead of sitting directly on the edge. As we will mostly use `left` and `right` options, it will have effect just for one node. But good to have it as general option in the scope.
- Place the main nodes
- Draw edges with nodes for description
- Use options `loop` and `bend` for loops and bent edges
- Specify `left` and `right` for bend direction and node placement

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,
                    thick,main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]

  \node[main node] (1) {1};
  \node[main node] (2) [below left of=1] {2};
  \node[main node] (3) [below right of=2] {3};
  \node[main node] (4) [below right of=1] {4};

  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge node [left] {0.6} (4)
        edge [bend right] node[left] {0.3} (2)
        edge [loop above] node {0.1} (1)
    (2) edge node [right] {0.4} (1)
        edge node {0.3} (4)
        edge [loop left] node {0.4} (2)
        edge [bend right] node[left] {0.1} (3)
    (3) edge node [right] {0.8} (2)
        edge [bend right] node[right] {0.2} (4)
    (4) edge node [left] {0.2} (3)
        edge [loop right] node {0.6} (4)
        edge [bend right] node[right] {0.2} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: graph with nodes and edges]

Comment: That is great! Two additional questions.
1. How can I modify this so it is numbered as figures? Is using `\begin{figure}\begin{tikzpicture}` correct?
2. How can I make the output bigger?

Comment: Question 3. How can I modify this so it doesn't change the font of entire document?

Comment: @Ichibann For an additional question, please post a new question instead of a comment, that's the way this question & answer site works. Check existing questions before. In short: 1) yes 2) bigger font, bigger node distance, or `scale` option 3) use `\sffamily` in the node style definition

Comment: Can you create this kind of graph [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/H41ER.jpg) with this pkg? Is there some "middle" directory? I am getting new nodes on top of each other [here](https://www.writelatex.com/317353txbpvy) :(

Comment: @hhh Sure, perhaps post your specific different problem as a new question, if you can describe it well, other than only "draw this for me" ;-) such as with your current code.

Answer (score 22):

I also suggest the amazing `automata` library, as seen in Stefan's answer. `:)`

Just for completeness sake, I'd like to add an answer with one the first packages I used for drawing graphs and automata before I found `TikZ`: the `vaucanson-g` package.

This package relies on `PSTricks`, so we need to compile the following example with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

% good old times
\usepackage{vaucanson-g}

\begin{document}

% first of all, we define our grid
\begin{VCPicture}{(0,-3)(6,3)}

% and then we create the states
\State[1]{(3,3)}{STATEA}
\State[2]{(0,0)}{STATEB}
\State[3]{(3,-3)}{STATEC}
\State[4]{(6,0)}{STATED}

% now, transition time

% straight lines
\EdgeR{STATEB}{STATEA}{0.2}
\EdgeR{STATEA}{STATED}{0.6}
\EdgeR{STATED}{STATEC}{0.2}
\EdgeR{STATEC}{STATEB}{0.8}
\EdgeR{STATEB}{STATED}{0.3}

% arcs
\LArcR{STATEA}{STATEB}{0.3}
\LArcR{STATEB}{STATEC}{0.1}
\LArcR{STATEC}{STATED}{0.2}
\LArcR{STATED}{STATEA}{0.2}

% loops
\LoopN{STATEA}{0.1}
\LoopW{STATEB}{0.4}
\LoopE{STATED}{0.6}

\end{VCPicture}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: The output]

There we go. `:)`

Answer (score 14):

I combine tkz-graph and tikz.

**Picture**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,thick]
% unit
\SetGraphUnit{3} 
% styles
\GraphInit[vstyle=Normal] 
\SetVertexNormal[Shape=circle,MinSize=1cm,LineWidth =1pt]
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.append style = {font=\Large\bfseries},thick} 
% vertices  
\Vertex{1} 
\SOWE(1){2} 
\SOEA(2){3} 
\SOEA(1){4} 
% intern edges
\Edges(2,4,3,2,1,4) 
% loops
\Loop[dist=3cm,dir=NO,style={thick},label=$0.1$,labelstyle=above](1)  
\Loop[dist=3cm,dir=WE,style={thick},label=$0.4$,labelstyle=left](2)  
\Loop[dist=3cm,dir=EA,style={thick},label=$0.6$,labelstyle=right](4)
% intern labels 
\path[every node/.style={swap,auto}]    (2) to node {0.3} (4)
                                            to node {0.2} (3)
                                            to node {0.8} (2)
                                            to node {0.4} (1)
                                            to node {0.6} (4); 
% draw extern edges and label
\draw[<-] (1) to [bend left] node [above right] {0.2} (4);
\draw[<-] (4) to [bend left] node [below right] {0.2} (3);
\draw[<-] (3) to [bend left] node [below left]  {0.1} (2);  
\draw[<-] (2) to [bend left] node [above left]  {0.3} (1);      

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```